# Unable to use observable value in nested httpservice.get call - race condition

Tags: axios, rxjs, nestjs, observable, race-condition

I am getting some strange issue, I have 2 http axios calls,
Call 1: POST: this call return stateId
Call 2: GET : this call uses stateId and returns cities of that particular state

```
const cities = this.httpService.post('https://getAlldata/getStates', body, headers).pipe(
        
switchMap((stateResponse: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
        console.log(stateResponse.data.stateId) //stateId is getting printed on console                
        
        const headers2 = {
                          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
                          params: { stateID: stateResponse.data.stateId } // first POST response stateId is used here
                        }
                         
                        return this.httpService.get(URL, headers2);
                      }),
                      map((resp2: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
                        return resp2.data
                      }),
                )
```

In above code, I am getting error saying that `stateID not passed`, this is looking like race condition issue where call 2 is getting executed before getting stateID

If I just pass hard-coded stateId in the params like below:

```
params: { stateID: 23 }
```

I am able to get the response from call 2 i.e. Get Http request

the another thing is that if I just put some timeout of 3 seconds then I am getting the response from call 2 without passing hard-coded value.

The another mystery is that if I just do console.log () then value is printed on console

I have searched a lot on stack-overflow, but did not found a way to wait until Call 1 resolves the value, I want to achieve this without adding timeout or delay.

Instead of using timeout, there should be some mechanism to wait until Http Call 1 gives us the result.

I have tried to use `mergeMap` and `concatMap` to resolve this but it does not helps.

Also `tried to convert observable to Promise` and used chained `.then()` but still it does not helped.

I have tried `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` but not luck

Also tried `Async/await` but not helped

Comment: How can your code work ? `firstValueFrom` returns a Promise and you can't `pipe()` a Promise.

Comment: Your response is called `stateResponse`, but in your second call you are passing `response.data.stateId`. Is this a typo?

Comment: This example is unjust; not working. `console.log(response.data.stateId)` where is response declared?

Comment: Does `stateResponse.data` actually have a property `stateId`. What does the exact error look like?

Comment: @YoupBernoulli I can not paste my actual code due to due to company policy. I have created dummy example from my actual code issue, please correct small issues